# Function from controller to service of factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, ionic-framework

This function is inside controller, and is activated by clicked button in view, can i put this to .service or .factory so i can free up my controller for better code view, and how?

```
$scope.promjeni5 = function () {

    if(sk5 === kockice[0].src) {
      m5 = kockice[0].src;
      sk5 = document.getElementById("sk5").src = zkockice[0].src;
      } else if(sk5 === kockice[1].src) {
       m5 = kockice[1].src;
      sk5 = document.getElementById("sk5").src = zkockice[1].src;
      } else if(sk5 === kockice[2].src) {
      m5 = kockice[2].src;
      sk5 = document.getElementById("sk5").src = zkockice[2].src;
      } else if(sk5 === kockice[3].src) {
      m5 = kockice[3].src;
      sk5 = document.getElementById("sk5").src = zkockice[3].src;
      } else if(sk5 === kockice[4].src) {
      m5 = kockice[4].src;
      sk5 = document.getElementById("sk5").src = zkockice[4].src;
      } else if(sk5 === kockice[5].src) {
      m5 = kockice[5].src;
      sk5 = document.getElementById("sk5").src = zkockice[5].src;
      } else {
      sk5 = document.getElementById("sk5").src = m5;
      }
    }
```

//this is how its triggered in view

Comment: You would want to put it into a directive rather than a service or factory. You shouldn't ever use a service/factory to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Before moving it to a factory you could rewrite in angular. Don't assign directly to the `src` attribute of a DOM element: use `ng-src="something"` in the HTML template and then just update `$scope.something` from the controller.